# Does Glide automatically prevent duplicate calls?

Tags: android, android-glide

Will Glide automatically ignore the second call in the following code? Or will I get 2 separate HTTP requests? Also if it does automatically ignore the second call, is it just "most of the time" or "guaranteed thread-safe always only once"?

```
Glide.with(context).downloadOnly().load(some_url).into(500, 500);
Glide.with(context).downloadOnly().load(some_url).into(500, 500);
```

Comment: Glide will automatically load the images from the cache if there is the image then it will not load otherwise it will from the network. I think there is an option in Glide where you can check the image loading is from disk memory or network same as in Picasso.

Comment: You can a find a good tutorial about Glide on https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at their [RequestBuilder](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.java) class.

It seems they check if there is a previous request, and if it there is one that is equivalent to the new one your are making, they re-use it, and if it is not running (or done) they begin it.

So if your first request is still running, it will just give it a chance to continue running and will not re-deliver results.

If the previous request failed or is already done, it will start it again, and re-deliver results.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.